# Android: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Fragment class here" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-library, dex, android-multidex

I'm working on a library module project that contains its own UX/UI with a single activity and a navigation graph using Navigation Component. I'm in the process of taking that module, publishing a release variant of it with `minifyEnabled true` and Proguard rules to a personal Github Packages repo, and implementing it in a fresh Android project. Aside from the standard `Proguard` rules and `ConsumerProguardFiles` specifically for library modules from what I read, I'm now at the stage where when I attempt to launch the module's activity in the fresh project, I get the following error at the top of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.example.packagename/com.example2.packagename2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31 in com.example.packagename:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #31 in com.example.packagename:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

MainActivity xml hosts the navigation graph

I get the following error at the end of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyFragmentClass
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadClass(FragmentFactory.java:53)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(FragmentFactory.java:94)
   ... 50 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MyFragmentClass" on path: DexPathList...
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
   ... 54 more
```

MyFragmentClass is the entry fragment for the navigation graph.

I thought this was Proguard at work here, but I wrote -keep rules in the ConsumerProguardFiles file to explicitly keep the fragment class.

```
-keep class packagename.MyFragmentClass
```

And did so for all Fragment classes with destinations in the graph to be safe. No changes in error logs there.

I read that this may have to do with multiDex not being used, so I followed steps from
https://developer.android.com/build/multidex#keep; extending my custom application to `MultiDexApplication()` and moved the keep rules from the `consumerProguardFiles file` for the fragment destinations into this `multidex-config.pro file` from the documentation, but I'm still hitting the same issue with `ClassNotFoundException.`

I've been at this for a long while now, and I'm unsure how else to proceed. This doesn't happen when I run a non-minified aar published to github packages, so something is definitely being obfuscated.

The `DexPathList` from the error log above, currently after enabling MultiDex and rule changes associated with it, is here:

```
DexPathList: [[dex file "/data/data/com.example.packagename/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~6kA_gImFoxVpIpGEWOAh9g==/com.example.packagename-gdFV1iEfqaX11tSq9odycQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~6kA_gImFoxVpIpGEWOAh9g==/com.example.packagename-gdFV1iEfqaX11tSq9odycQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~6kA_gImFoxVpIpGEWOAh9g==/com.example.packagename-gdFV1iEfqaX11tSq9odycQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
```

Any help for this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!